# Bulk QR codes Generation

Tags: qr-code

Is there a way to create bulk CR codes to pull data from an excel sheet and insert them to email. Ie if I have a list of serial numbers. One serial number per QR code that can be inserted into the body of the email.

Comment: there are methods to create QR codes within Excel and a number of ways to export the information, but the missing information is "email." What email system are you using?

Comment: Hello. The email that I would be using is outlook. What I need it to do is have the codes generated and then when it’s scanned it will open the  email client on a customers phone and have all the info populated into an email so that the customer can just hit send

Comment: Considering the level of security of Outlook, are you able to open a received email in your Outlook account, which is represented by a QR code generated elsewhere? This sort of test would allow you to determine if the effort is validated.

Comment: Yes I would be able to do that

Comment: You would be able to test as suggested, or you have tested and are able to open an email via a QR code? It's best if you can create or access an account other than the sending account, to more properly validate the test.